# Sort ArrayList but keep order of the original indexes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

There are two int arrays and an array list called costs and shipping. I want an ArrayList that has the smallest to the largest total price (for example costs[0] + shipping[0]) but reorder the two int arrays to match the ArrayList:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
int[] costs = new int[n];
int[] shipping = new int[n];
ArrayList<Integer> totalCosts = new ArrayList<>();
```

For example, say that costs is [1, 5, 2, 3] and shipping is [2, 3, 2, 4], so totalCosts would be  {3, 8, 4, 7} and would be sorted to {3, 4, 7, 8}. I want costs and shipping to be reordered so they correspond to the totals, so costs would be [1, 2, 3, 5] and shipping would be [2, 2, 4, 3].

Comment: you want that and what have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: That is very hard to do as you would need to move the array elements based on how the list elements were move by the sorting. It's easier to create a new class that contains costs, shipping and the totalprice. Then make a list of those and sort that.

Comment: Generally, having [multiple collections that must be maintained in parallel is a bad idea](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). I would create a `List<Order>` where the Order class has 2 fields, cost and shipping, and a method `getTotal` which sums them. It then becomes trivial to sort with [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) and since data is logically grouped into objects, the indexes are maintained automatically. You can break that out again into new arrays if you really have to

Comment: Using a HashMap here may be even better, and then just call sort on you map, since the default sort is stable there shouldnt be any issues!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not use a map. Instead we have a custom Comparator that uses the sum of costs and shipping to sort the array positions. Then we create new arrays and pick the values from the sorted positions in the old arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    int[] costs = {1, 5, 2, 3};
    int[] shipping = {2, 3, 2, 4};
    Integer[] totals = new Integer[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        totals[i] = i;
    }

    Arrays.sort(totals, Comparator.comparingInt(k -> (costs[k] + shipping[k])));

    int[] newCosts = new int[n];
    int[] newShipping = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        newCosts[i] = costs[totals[i]];
        newShipping[i] = shipping[totals[i]];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ": Cost=" + newCosts[i] + ", Shipping=" + newShipping[i] + ", Total=" + (newCosts[i] + newShipping[i]));
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The totals array contains the list of index from 0 to n (4 in the sample). `Arrays.sort()` sorts the index using the Comparator which, given an index, extracts the totals for that position. The totals array will, after sorting, list index of the sums of cost and shipping in order.

After that we can create new cost and shipping arrays using the sorted indexes.

**Edit**

Taking ttzn's advice from the comments, you can compress the code to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    int[] costs = {1, 5, 2, 3};
    int[] shipping = {2, 3, 2, 4};

    int[] totals = IntStream.range(0, n).boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> (costs[(int)k] + shipping[(int)k]))).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

    int[] newCosts = IntStream.of(totals).map(i -> costs[i]).toArray();
    int[] newShipping = IntStream.of(totals).map(i -> shipping[i]).toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ": Cost=" + newCosts[i] + ", Shipping=" + newShipping[i] + ", Total=" + (newCosts[i] + newShipping[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're going Java 8 with `comparingInt`, you might as well go `int[] totals = IntStream.range(0, n)` and `int[] newCosts = IntStream.of(totals).map(i -> costs[i]).toArray();`

Comment: Good point. I agree that is a better choice though it might be harder to understand if you're not familiar with streams.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Integer> sortPrices(int[] cost, int[] shipping) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<Integer, List<int[]>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    int length = cost.length;
    int[] origCost = new int[length];
    int[] origShipping = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int price = cost[i] + shipping[i];
        int[] arr = {i, i};
        map.putIfAbsent(price, new ArrayList<>());
        map.get(price).add(arr);
        origCost[i] = cost[i];
        origShipping[i] = shipping[i];
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int price : map.keySet()) {
        for (int[] arr : map.get(price)) {
            int ci = arr[0];
            int si = arr[1];
            cost[j] = origCost[ci];
            shipping[j] = origShipping[si];
            j++;
            result.add(price);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The above should work. the map is a tree map with key as the total price and value is a list of arrays of length 2. List has to be used as we may have the same total prices more than once. The rest, I believe, is self explainable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in python

just understand the loop logic, you will be able to do it then.

```
for i in range(len(total)):
  for j in range(len(total)):
    if sorted_total[i]==total[j]:
        new_costs[i]=costs[j]
        new_shipping[i]=shipping[j]
        print("i ",i)
        print("j ",j)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stream based solution without building a map.

1. A `Stream<int[]>` is built storing a total and index in `int[]` array,
2. The stream is sorted using a custom comparator for these arrays (first by total, then by index)
3. Intentionally use `peek` along with `AtomicInteger` to reorder input `costs` and `ships` arrays
   *Note*: However, this may be considered as an "abuse" aggravated by side-effect update of data *outside* the stream
4. Build and return the array of totals.

```java
public static int[] getTotals(int[] costs, int[] ships) {
    assert costs.length == ships.length;
    int[] copyCosts = Arrays.copyOf(costs, costs.length);
    int[] copyShips = Arrays.copyOf(ships, ships.length);
    
    AtomicInteger ix = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    return IntStream.range(0, costs.length)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{ costs[i] + ships[i], i })
                    .sorted(Comparator.<int[]>
                        comparingInt(p -> p[0])
                        .thenComparingInt(p -> p[1])
                    ) // get sorted Stream<int[]>
                    .peek(p -> {
                        costs[ix.get()] = copyCosts[p[1]];
                        ships[ix.getAndIncrement()] = copyShips[p[1]];
                    })
                    .mapToInt(p -> p[0])
                    .toArray();
}
```